# Transmitting sound from my TV to my android phone

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have android TV in my bedroom.
I have nexus 5 phone as well. 
How can I transmit the sound from my tv to my phone so I can use my headphone, is that possible?
I don't have Bluetooth headphones... Just regular ones connected to the phone.
Thanks

Comment: Please specify you TV. Most smart TV's, if they have Bluetooth, are usually only for receiving and not for transmitting. Your would most likely need an external Bluetooth transmitter with matching aptX headphones.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of variables that will determine whether this can be done, especially without additional hardware. So far, I've only found one app that can [mostly] produce the audio of TV stations: [Tunity on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tunityapp.tunityapp). This app seems limited to certain stations and does not actually stream audio from the television itself.

Android phones are not really set up to use as a Bluetooth receiver. Most devices are configured to disable the headphone port when Bluetooth is connected. You can stream *to* the TV from the device, but not to the device from the TV.